# How do you give the content of a node a margin/padding without using html within the node?

Tags: nodes

How would you go about giving an entire node (the content) a margin or padding to the edge of the node - without using html within the node - in drupal?

1. Is there a module for this?
2. If not - how do you do so using CSS?

Comment: Have you ever heard of css? It requires 0 html and 0 php.

Comment: Why yes of course - but what is the css class/tag for the entire content of a node? 
I thought people might answer with a module that did it or otherwise explain the CSS needed

Comment: it varies per whatever theme you use. it's typically something like `div.node` or `div.node div.content` as an example. tools like Firebug and Chrome developer tools can show you what classes a piece of content has in your HTML page. Using DisplaySuite for example you could provide additional classe(s) to any piece of view_mode -- but the basic markup exists per theme to target a nodes output on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it varies per whatever theme you use. it's typically something like div.node or div.node div.content as an example. tools like Firebug and Chrome developer tools can show you what classes a piece of content has in your HTML page. Using DisplaySuite for example you could provide additional classe(s) to any piece of content within view_mode -- but the basic markup exists per theme to target a nodes output on the screen.

It not only varies per whatever theme your using, but if your theme is HTML5 vs HTML4 (why in this day in age, i dunno) it may be `article.node` as a CSS selector because `article` is a new HTML5 element type, vs say a plain old `div.node` in older versions of HTML.